# Swift でメンバ変数に自分自身のクラスの型を持つと実行時に Unknown class としてエラー

Tags: swift, xcode6

こんにちは。

XCode + Swift の環境で iOS 向けの開発をしています。XCodeのバージョンは、 6.1.1 です。

クラス内に、自分自身のクラスの型の変数を宣言するとビルドは通るのですが、実行時にエラーとなります。ネットで検索すると、"Build Phases" の "Compile Sources" に入れるとかあるのですが、すでに入っています。またカスタムビューなどを使っているわけでもありません。

エラー内容:

```
Unknown class X in Interface Builder file.
```

ソースは以下となります:

```
import UIKit

class MyClass {

    var id : String = ""
    var name : String = ""
    var parent:MyClass = MyClass() // ←ここでEXE_BAD_ACCESSになります
    var children:[MyClass] = Array()

    init(){
    }

    init(id:String, name:String){
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }

    func addChild(child:MyClass){
        child.parent = self
        self.children.append(child)
    }

    func isBlank() -> Bool{
        return id.isEmpty
    }

}
```

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyClassを作成すると同時にparent.parent.parent…を無限に作成しようとしてスタックオーバーフローしているのではないでしょうか。nil等に変更する必要があると思います。